# Kotlin parsing JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, parsing

i'm new to kotlin and JSON parsing, and am having troubles getting this to work I set up an api in php to jsonencode my mysql response and have kotlin using volly to connect to the server but when trying to parse it in kotlin it is giving me a mismatch, i'm not sure what the problem with the output is, maybe the square brackets? Is there a way to get rid of those so it can read it, or is there something i can do on the kotlin side?

```
private fun retriveProperties() {
        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("#####", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var username = sharedPref.getString("user", null)
        val password = sharedPref.getString("pas", null)
        val url = "https://www.#########.com/api/getproperties.php?user="+username+"&pass="+password
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                response ->try {
            val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                val employee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val firstName = employee.getString("FName")
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, firstName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> error.printStackTrace() })
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }
```

stack trace is:

```
2021-08-02 21:52:02.322 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":"1","FName":"#########","LName":"#########","Email":"##################@#########.com","Username":"#########","Password#########","Tel":"#########","LotID":"1","Price":"1.0","Often":"BiWeekly","JLevel":"2","Subscription":"0","Active":"1","OrderID":"#########","PPemail":"##################@gmail.com","PPname":"######### #########","PPID":"#########"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
2021-08-02 21:52:02.322 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:90)
2021-08-02 21:52:02.323 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:144)
2021-08-02 21:52:02.323 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2021-08-02 21:52:02.323 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2021-08-02 21:52:02.323 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err: Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"ID":"1","FName":"#########","LName":"#########","Email":"##################@#########.com","Username":"#########","Password#########","Tel":"#########","LotID":"1","Price":"1.0","Often":"BiWeekly","JLevel":"2","Subscription":"0","Active":"1","OrderID":"#########","PPemail":"##################@gmail.com","PPname":"######### #########","PPID":"#########"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
2021-08-02 21:52:02.323 19237-19237/com.#########.######### W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
```

i tried `trim($json, '[]')` on the server side, that didn't work as then kotlin complained it wasn't real JSON.... so now looking into other solutions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't solve the JSON issue, but i got my information by changing the string to

```
info1|info2|info3|etc
```

then on kotlin side

```
val lstValues: List<String> = response.split("|").map { it -> it.trim() }

var fname = lstValues.elementAt(0)
var lname = lstValues.elementAt(1)
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Welcome "+fname + " "+lname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. It says you are trying to parse a `JSONArray` as `JSONObject`. The response you received is in this pattern `[{user: "USER1"}, {user: "USER2"}]` and you are trying to read it like `{user: "USER1"}`. You response can have multiple objects since you have wrapped it in an array. In my understanding that won't be the case and you would receive only 1 User Object. So either you change the server response to object and the code would work on FE. Else if you need it to be an array, you can change FE code to parse `JSONArray` and iterate to get the JSON Objects.

Answer (score 0):

User Model needs to have a Serializable implementation.

```
data class User(
    var id: String,
    var FName: String,
    ...
) : Serializable
```

Then take the value from JSON array and add to a list

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
var users: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()

for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    var user = Gson().fromJson(jsonArray[i].toString(), User::class.java)
    users.add(user)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson instead, add it in your app `build.gradle` like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
```

Then you can define your object model, e.g:

```kotlin
data class User(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id : String,

    @SerializedName("Fname")
    val Fname : String
)
```

You can parse the json to using something like this:

```
val user = Gson().fromJson<User>("{}")
```